# column mixed with ID and item in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables below within the system. Subscription table contain the ID of pdt table and the item, while the product table contain the ID of the subscription table.

I am trying to obtain the results as shown below :

[image]

Should I create a new subscription table -> create a column for ID in subscription table , 2nd column to contain magazine etc. Same applies for product table. Then use the join function?

Comment: Is this your tables structure? Can you please show us the real structure?

Comment: provides proper format of table

Comment: Hi sorry, I do not have the proper table structure info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend actually not even creating a new table.  If you just want a CSV list of subscriptions and their products, just use a query to generate that:

```
SELECT
    'Subscription ' + t1.Magazine + ', Product ' + t2.Magazine
FROM subscription t1
INNER JOIN product t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

The reason I recommend not creating your proposed table is that everything it would contain would just be a rehash of data already stored elsewhere in your database.  It therefore represents a waste of space.  You could consider using a materialized view if you need the output from the above query with high performance.

Comment: Initially i thought of using inner join function but i realized under the result, the subscription and product table do not have the ID anymore.

Comment: Hi, I have figured out the rest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to JOIN your tables and concat as:

```
SELECT 'Subscription '+T1.Item+', product '+T2.Magazine
FROM Subscription T1 INNER JOIN Product T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID;
```